# Are my files lost after I executed mv /parentdir/otherparentdir/somedir/* /parentdir/destdir/?

Tags: command-line, bash, mv

I was trying to move all the files in a dir to another dir. I got errors at the first 2 attempts but at 3rd attempt it appeared the command did succeed. However the source dir is now empty but the files are not at the dest directory. 
Are they gone or is there a way I can recover them?

Here are the commands I executed (`Downloads` is at `/DataVolume/shares/Public` dir):

```
$ cd /DataVolume/shares/Public
$ shopt -s dotglob
$ mv -i Downloads/* /DataVolume/shares/Ricardo/Downloads
mv: target `/DataVolume/shares/Ricardo/Downloads' is not a directory
$ mv -i Downloads/* /DataVolume/shares/Ricardo/Downloads/
mv: target `/DataVolume/shares/Ricardo/Downloads/' is not a directory
$ mv -i Downloads/* /DataVolume/shares/Ricardo/
```

After executing the last command I looked into `/DataVolume/shares/Ricardo/` but the files are not there. Then I went to look at `/DataVolume/shares/Public/Downloads` and 
it's now empty.

**UPDATE**
If I execute the command `ll /DataVolume/shares/Ricardo/` i get this

```
$ ll /DataVolume/shares/Ricardo/
total 11252
drwxrwxr-x  5 root     share      32768 Feb 13  2016 zzzzzz ADirectory
drwxrwxr-x  2 root     share       4096 Feb 12  2016 rrrrrr ADirectory
-rw-rwxr-x  1 root     share    5741378 Feb 12  2016 xxxxx.dmg
drwxrwxrwx 15 www-data www-data    4096 May 16  2018 Documents
drwxrwsr-x  8 ricardo  share       4096 Feb 26  2017 DocumentsOld
-rw-rwxr-x  1 root     share    3514909 Feb 12  2016 yyyyyy.dmg
drwxrwsr-x  7 ricardo  share       4096 Jan 29  2016 OtherDir2
drwxrwxr-x  3 ricardo  share       4096 May 16  2018 OtherDir
drwxrwsr-x  2 ricardo  share       4096 Sep 30  2015 Other Dir3
-rw-rwxr-x  1 root     share    2188642 Feb 12  2016 zzzzz.tar.tar.gz
```

One thing I can notice is the datetime for `.` in `/DataVolume/shares/Ricardo/` is the same that the the datetime for `/DataVolume/shares/Public/Downloads`

```
/DataVolume/shares/Ricardo$ ls -hal
drwxrwx---+ 10 root     share    4.0K Sep 22 09:23 .
drwxrwxr-x  11 root     share    4.0K Sep 22 09:06 ..
...
```

```
/DataVolume/shares/Public$ ls -hal
...
drwxrwxr-x   2 root    share 4.0K Sep 22 09:23 Downloads
...
```

Comment: Can you update your question with what `ll /DataVolume/shares/Ricardo/` returns?

Comment: You didn't use specific or relative directory nomenclature, and your files ended up in the root of your hard disk. See `ls -al /` and you'll find them.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix question updated. Thank you

Comment: @heynnema I've already looked for them with `ls -hal` on root dir but they are not there. In fact the root dir doesn't show any file. Only directories and all of them were already there before. Also the `.` datetime at the `/` dir has an old update date so I think it means nothing has changed in the dir.

Comment: @heynnema the target path `/DataVolume/shares/Ricardo/` is absolute, surely?

Comment: @steeldriver but where is that directory path? I'd more expect something like /media/blah/blah/blah or /mnt/blah/blah/blah or /home/blah/blah/blah. Very confusing mv command.

Answer (score 0):

I just figured out that the command was in fact successful. I just didn't remember which files were in `Downloads` dir. After examining files and sizes and making a test with `touch` and `make dir` and executing the same last `mv` command I could check the command was executing correctly and the files were being moved as expected.
Thank you anyway [@wineunuuchs2unix](https://askubuntu.com/users/307523/wineunuuchs2unix) and [@heynnema](https://askubuntu.com/users/4272/heynnema) for your attention.

Comment: You know, of course, that you can move a whole directory at once by doing 'mv Downloads /DataVolume/shares/Ricardo'. Much quicker too if there are a lot of files/subdirectories in the source.